# How to deploy the next.js app to the Cpanel?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to deploy next.js app to Cpanel but I have some difficulties, it is not working. I have done the following steps.

1. Cpanel node version is 14.17.3 and I also upgraded my node version.
2. Create setup.js file.
3. Change "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js", in package.json.
4. npm run build
5. took all folders except node_modules and deployed Cpanel.
6. setup node.js in Cpanel and install node_modules.
7. run js.script as npm run start but it gives following error
   npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts
8. I create .npmrc file and put it inside
   'scripts-prepend-node-path=true'
   still website is not working just show the folders structure

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?. Thanks in advance